# I wanna make my code better but don't know how at this point. I'd like someone else's opnion to tell me how can I improve

Tags: javascript

So a friend of mine asked if I could do a function that compresses strings. That function compresses a string if one character repeats itself more than four times, like: "abbbbbbcccdddd" will turn into "a#6bccc#4d". I'm noob and I wanna improve. Thank u for who is answering me :).

```js
let text = '92HSSSS9U27888YSGGGGGG28SLKHFKLSPPPPSKWWW'

function compressText(text){
    return searchIqualLetters(text)
}

function searchIqualLetters(originalText){
    let modifyedText = ''

    for(let i = 0; i < originalText.length - 1; i++){

        for(let j = i + 1; j < originalText.length; j++){
            
            modifyedText = repeatFourTimes(i, j, originalText)
            if(modifyedText !== undefined && modifyedText !== ''){
                originalText = modifyedText
            }
        }
    }
    return originalText
}

function checkTextModifyed(){

}

function repeatFourTimes(i, j, text){
    if(text[i] == text[j] && text[i] == text[j + 1] && text[i] == text[j + 2]){
        return getLastIqualLetter(i, j, text)
    }
}

function getLastIqualLetter(i, j, text){
    let lastIqualLetterPosition = 0

    for(let k = 0; text[i] == text[j + k]; k++){
        lastIqualLetterPosition = j + k
    }

    return makeNewText(i, lastIqualLetterPosition, text)
}

function makeNewText(i, lastLetter, text){
    let cutedPart = text.slice(i, lastLetter + 1)

    let startPart = text.slice(0, i)
    let centerPart = '#' + cutedPart.length + cutedPart[0]
    let endPart = text.slice(lastLetter + 1, text.length)
    
    return startPart + centerPart + endPart 
}

console.log(compressText(text)) // Result: 92H#4S9U27888YS#6G28SLKHFKLS#4PSKWWW
```

Comment: [codereview.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take on the problem:

```js
function condense(text) {
    let count = 0;
    let out = "";
    text.split("").forEach((el, i, arr) => { // el = current letter, i = index of letter, arr = the input text as an array
        if (arr[i + 1] != el) { // if the next letter is not the same as the current one
            if (count < 3) {
                out += el.repeat(count + 1) // if the sequence is less than 3 letters, then just do it normally
            } else {
                out += "#" + (count + 1) + el; // else, condense it
            }
            count = 0; // reset sequence length
        } else {
            count += 1; // increase count of repeated letter sequence length
        }
    })
    return out;
}
console.log(condense("aaabbbbcdddddee")); // Output: "aaab#4cd#5ee"

console.log(condense('92HSSSS9U27888YSGGGGGG28SLKHFKLSPPPPSKWWW'));
console.log("92H#4S9U27888YS#6G28SLKHFKLS#4PSKWWW (reference)");
```

Comment: I like your detail `arr[i + 1] != el`. This covers the "end of string case" very elegantly!

Comment: Ouh!! I'm impressed with how short it is! Thank u very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on it:

```js
const text = '92HSSSS9U27888YSGGGGGG28SLKHFKLSPPPPSKWWW';

function compr(txt){
  let  cnt=1,arr=[];
  txt.split("").reduce((p,c,i)=>{
    if(c==p) cnt++;
    if(c!=p || i==txt.length-1) {
     arr.push(cnt>3?`#${cnt}${p}`:p.repeat(cnt));
     cnt=1;
    }
    return c;
   });
   return arr.join("");
}

console.log(compr(text));
console.log("92H#4S9U27888YS#6G28SLKHFKLS#4PSKWWW (reference)");
```

The core of the action happens in the `.reduce()` loop. Here I compare the current character `c` with the previous one(`p`). If it is the same I simply increase the counter `cnt` otherwise - or in case I have reached the end of the string (`i==txt.length-1`) - I add the latest group of character in its suitable form to `arr` and reset `cnt` to `1`. The `arr` array is eventually `.join()`ed and returned as the resulting string.

Comment: It's so short!! I didn't know about this "reduce thing". Thanks for helping me and teaching me a new thing :)

Comment: You made the right choice: in this case I believe @TorNato's  `.forEach()` solution is actually better. The only thing that can still be approved is the concatenation of the target string. Since strings are immutable in JavaScript, building an array and joining it afterwards is generally faster.